# Best Practice: Use reference to objects in loop or plain array access?

Tags: c++98

I go an array of objects Data of let's say 100: Data data_array[100]. What would be the best practice to access these objects in a loop in c++98.

1.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
{
    Data& data_obj = data_array[i];
  // do a lot of with it, call functions and so on 
}
```

2.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
{
  // do a lot of with it, call functions and so on but always use data_array[i]
}
```

Is there a performance decrease when using method 1 over 2? Or will the compiler optimizations eliminate any differences anyway? 
What would be the preferred way to write code?

PS: I don't have a PC at hand to test out the performance myself.

Answer (score 0):

if you have dissasembler you could read the assembler code and check there are very little differences between the 2 ways.
In fact data_array[i] is always transformed in a temp variable..   but with the first way, i think the code is more readable